# how to get LOW bandwidth network access on Wear OS for rest call?

Tags: android, retrofit2, wear-os, okhttp, android-wear-2.0

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/network-access.html#network-access) we can read about wear 2+:

> Wear OS apps can make network requests. When a watch has a Bluetooth
>   connection to a phone, the watch's network traffic generally is
>   proxied through the phone. But when a phone is unavailable, Wi-Fi and
>   cellular networks are used, depending on the hardware. The Wear
>   platform handles transitions between networks.

so i can just use retrofit/volley/URLConnection as a standard phone app ?
or i need to use some special classes that made this switch ?

Comment: Did you see this: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer

Comment: none of the examples is my case

Comment: You should then clarify what your particular problem is. I thought the data flow image in the link I provided was clear. Either you are using WiFi/Cellular access or you are using the Google connector to your Android app for passing data. If you are using WiFi/Cellular then all of the usual HTTP/HTTPS libraries & techniques apply.

Comment: i rewrite completely the question

Comment: @MorrisonChang better now ?

Comment: Question is better, but if you have a Wear OS 2 device you should be able to write a simple app to check the behavior over bluetooth. I didn't realize that you were asking about a new Wear OS 2 feature and unfortunately I don't have a Wear OS 2 device to check.